# Streaming template gives the error "jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'stockStatus' is undefined"

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, webhooks, flask-socketio

I'm following a [tutorial](https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/webhooks-in-python-with-flask) on how to create a webhook using the Python Flask framework. The webhook is designed to enable communication between a client (webhook generator) and a server (webhook listener). The server has a file which contains stock keeping units and stock statuses ("In Stock" or "Out of Stock") of products. The objective is to allow the client to retrieve the stock status of specific products by sending HTTP POST requests to the server. However, I was unable to load the page for the webhook listener (`consumer.html`) and received the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\yuanl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2213, in __call__      
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\yuanl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask_socketio\__init__.py", line 43, in __call__
    return super(_SocketIOMiddleware, self).__call__(environ,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\yuanl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\engineio\middleware.py", line 74, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\yuanl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2193, in wsgi_app      
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\yuanl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2190, in wsgi_app      
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\yuanl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1486, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\yuanl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1484, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\yuanl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1469, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\yuanl\Documents\GitHub\Gelato-API-webhooks\inventory\app_consumer.py", line 18, in index
    return render_template('consumer.html')
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\yuanl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 151, in render_template
    return _render(app, template, context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\yuanl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 132, in _render 
    rv = template.render(context)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\yuanl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 1301, in render
    self.environment.handle_exception()
  File "C:\Users\yuanl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 936, in handle_exception
    raise rewrite_traceback_stack(source=source)
  File "C:\Users\yuanl\Documents\GitHub\Gelato-API-webhooks\inventory\templates\consumer.html", line 16, in top-level template code
    {% for SKU, Stock_status in stockStatus.items() %}
  File "C:\Users\yuanl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 485, in getattr
    return getattr(obj, attribute)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'stockStatus' is undefined
```

The code for the `consumer.html` Jinja template file is shown below:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Tasks Producer</title>
    <link href="../styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
  </head>
  <body class="container">
    <h1>Stock Sheet</h1>
    <table id="stockSheet">
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">SKU</th>
        <th scope="col">Stock Status</th>
      </tr>
    </table>
    {% for SKU, Stock_status in stockStatus.items() %}
        <script>
          var SKU = "{{SKU}}";
          var Stock_status = "{{Stock_status}}";
          document.getElementById("stockSheet").innerHTML += "<tr>" + "<td>"+ SKU + "</td>" + "<td>"+ Stock_status + "</td>" + "</tr>"
        </script>
    {% endfor %}
  </body>
</html>
```

The error in this file was that the variable `stockStatus` was undefined. However, the variable was defined in the `app_consumer.py` file that renders and streams the Jinja template file, specifically the `return Response(render_template_stream('consumer.html', stockStatus = tasks_consumer.sendStockStatus()))` statement. The relevant code segment in the file is show below:

```python
from flask import Response, render_template, request
from flask_socketio import join_room
from init_consumer import app, socketio
import tasks_consumer
import uuid

# Render a template with a given context as a stream and return a TemplateStream
def render_template_stream(template_name, **context):
    app.update_template_context(context)
    t = app.jinja_env.get_template(template_name)
    rv = t.stream(context)
    rv.enable_buffering(5)
    return rv

# Render the assigned template file
@app.route("/", methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return render_template('consumer.html')

# Registers a function to be run before the first request to this instance of the application
# Create a unique session ID and store it within the application configuration file
@app.before_request
def initialize_params():
    if not hasattr(app.config,'uid'):
        sid = str(uuid.uuid4())
        app.config['uid'] = sid
        print("initialize_params - Session ID stored =", sid)

@app.route('/consumetasks', methods=['POST'])
def get_stock_status():
    print("Retrieving stock status")
    return Response(render_template_stream('consumer.html', stockStatus = tasks_consumer.sendStockStatus()))
```

The code for the `tasks_consumer.py` file that defines the `sendStockStatus()` function is shown below:

```python
import csv
from flask import request
from init_consumer import app, socketio
import json

# Receive the webhook requests and emit a SocketIO event back to the client
def send_message(data):
    status_code = 0
    if request.method == 'POST':
        roomid = app.config['uid']
        msg = json.dumps(data)
        event = "Send_stock_status"
        socketio.emit(event, msg, namespace = '/collectHooks', room = roomid)
        status_code = 200
    else:
        status_code = 405 # Method not allowed
    return status_code
    
# Retrieve the stock status of the products sent through the webhook requests and return them back to the client.   
def sendStockStatus():
    SKUlist = []
    stockSheet = {}
    with open("NZ_NVJ_Apparel_SKUs_sheet.csv", newline='') as csvFile:
        stockReader = csv.reader(csvFile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
        for row in stockReader:
            SKUlist.append(row[0])
    if request.method == 'POST':
        stockInfo = request.json
        stockStr = str(stockInfo)
        stockStr = stockStr.replace("\'", "\"")
        stockDict = json.loads(stockStr)
        for stock in stockDict["SKU"]:
            if stock in SKUlist:
                stockSheet.update({str(stock):"In Stock"})
            else:
                stockSheet.update({str(stock):"Out of Stock"})
    send_message(stockSheet)
    return stockSheet
```

I don't understand what caused the error. I used the same code format in the Jinja template file as written in the [Jinja documentation](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#for) and the tutorial to iterate through the `stockStatus` dictionary returned by the `sendStockStatus()` function in the `tasks_consumer.py` file. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: It looks like your stack trace points to line 18 of your Python file. This is where you render consumer.html without passing the required arguments.